# Does AWS IAM support a policy that permits all accounts within an AWS Organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an account for which I wish to enable cross-account access.  To that end, I need an IAM policy that specifies all the accounts for which I would like to grant access as a list of Principals, for instance:

```
"Principal": { "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root", ...more accounts here... ] }
```

All the accounts to which I wish to grant access are within an AWS Organization, to which accounts are added frequently.  Is there a way of specifying all accounts within an Organization within a policy, without me needing to redeploy my policy when a new account is created?

It would be nice to be able to add an account to an Organization and have this account automatically added to the policy without needing to explicitly add it.

Comment: Is this an XY problem where what you really want is SSO? https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/

Answer (score 2):

Would the `aws:PrincipalOrgID` condition be able to help here?:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObject",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": [
                        "o-yyyyyyyyyy"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::2018-Financial-Data/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[See the AWS docs here for more](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/control-access-to-aws-resources-by-using-the-aws-organization-of-iam-principals/)